# Google Analytics non-interaction implementations (ni=1 vs nonInteraction:true)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a question regarding two seemingly different ways to implement sending an event in google analytics as a non-interaction hit type.

**(1) Protocol docs:**
 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ni

In query param:

```
&ni=1

/collect?v=1&t=event&ni=1
```

**(2) Analytics dev guide:**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign', {
  nonInteraction: true
});
```

which I inferred allows me to do this:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event'
  eventCategory: 'myCategory',
  eventAction: 'myAction',
  eventLabel: 'myLabel',
  nonIteraction: true
});
```

However, when I look at the network traffic in the chrome browser dev console I **do not see the "ni=1"** url parameter. Here is a list of the parameters that are present (values excluded):

v:
_v:
a:
t:
_s:
cd:
dl:
dp:
ul:
de:
dt:
sd:
sr:
vp:
je:
ec:
ea:
an:
av:
aid:
aiid:
_u:
jid:
gjid:
cid:
tid:
_gid:
z:

What is the difference betweeen these two implementations, and are the end results the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have both a server-side and JavaScript implementation of Google Analytics event tracking and in my experience they are treated exactly the same.

In my server-side implementation I send a payload directly to the `/collect` location with query parameters exactly as you posted (including `&ni=1`).

In JavaScript, I'm using the same syntax as you with `{'nonInteraction': true}` as my fieldsObject. Seemingly the only difference is I put `nonInteraction` in quotes (but I wouldn't think that would be enough to prevent it- worth a try).

I can see the `ni=1` show up in my console when I use the Google Analytics debugger (here is part of the log):

[image: GA Debugger Log]

And here it is in the Network tab itself:

[image: Network Tab GA payload]

I would double check that your `t` parameter is in fact `event` and double check that you're inspecting the correct one (maybe there is a chance you're looking at a different event)?

I'd also try installing the [Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) (even temporarily) for a more visual representation of each payload in the console.

Google Analytics does not treat those two methods you posted differently, so the `ni` parameter should be in there if the event you're sending is in fact written as you posted. Maybe someone else can glean some additional ideas from what you posted, but to me it seems everything is properly implemented.

Comment: Awesome man! I'm just happy to know that the url params look the same (server side vs browser xhr), and more importantly I know how to confirm success. I'll try the quotes and relay the results here :p

Comment: I just tested my JS implementation by taking the quotes out and it still worked, so it's still worth a test, but I think my suspicion that it is unrelated is likely correct. There must be *something* else going on- maybe even cached JS?

Comment: You are correct, it is unrelated. It was a ****ing typo. 2 hours of my life. Thanks again man, your comment was what prompted me to recheck everything and eventually confirm the "ni" parameter was correctly included in the url.

Comment: As much as it sucks that it was a typo- just be glad it was that simple! Glad to see you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my original question:
Yes - the end result of both implementations is the same. Both should include the "ni=1" url parameter.

If you do not see this in the dev console network traffic or in your server logs there is a mistake. In my case, my mistake is evident in my original post - notice the typo:

`nonIteraction: true`

should've been:

`nonInteraction: true`